# What's a cleaner way to output HTML from a Wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

My Wordpress plugin creates a few shortcodes that return blocks of HTML.

When I register the shortcodes, I do so like this:

```
    add_shortcode('bb-loans-form', function() {
        return Shortcodes::loanApplicationForm();
    });
```

And here is the static method from the Shortcodes class:

```
public static function loadApplicationForm()
{
    $form = new \AdamWathan\Form\FormBuilder;

    $html = $form->open()->action('/apply')->class('bb-loan-form');

    $html .= '<div class="bb-form-field">';
    $html .= '<h2>Loan Application Number</h2>';
    $html .= $form->text('loan_app_number')->id('loan-app-number');
    $html .= $form->submit('Continue Loan');
    $html .= '</div>';
    $html .= $form->close();

    return $html;
}
```

This is very cumbersome, and messy. I don't like outputting the HTML like this. I've also used Heredoc, but I had to use string substitution to include important values when the form is rendered.

Is there a better way to store my HTML files? I don't want these files publicly accessible. They would have to live in my plugin directory.

It's not a huge plugin, so I'm not overly concerned, but I'd like to know for future reference if there's a cleaner way to include the needed HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use a single string with concatenations...

```
$form = new \AdamWathan\Form\FormBuilder;
$html = $form->open()->action('/apply')->class('bb-loan-form') .
           '<div class="bb-form-field">
                <h2>Loan Application Number</h2>' .
                $form->text('loan_app_number')->id('loan-app-number') . 
                $form->submit('Continue Loan') .
           '</div>' .
        $form->close();

return $html;
```

It at least keeps the HTML aligned.

I also don't really see an issue with Heredoc, as long as you assign variables and substitute them in:

```
$form = new \AdamWathan\Form\FormBuilder;

$form_start = $form->open()->action('/apply')->class('bb-loan-form');
$loan_app = $form->text('loan_app_number')->id('loan-app-number');
$submit = $form->submit('Continue Loan');
$form_end = $form->close();

$html = <<<HTML
    {$form_start}
        <div class="bb-form-field">
            <h2>Loan Application Number</h2>
            {$loan_app}
            {$submit}
        </div>
    {$form_end}
HTML; 

return $html;
```

Comment: I'm currently using the Heredoc solution in one of the complex forms. I'm new to WP plugin development, so I was hoping there would be some sort of layer in the Wordpress core that deals with view/output rendering.